# Process builder - Create child records using the parent record id

Tags: process-builder

I am creating a child record on creation of lead using Process builder. This works except that it cannot take the parent record id into child record. This is always blank.

[image]

Is there a way we can create a child record and link it up with the parent record using process builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have replicated your use case at my DE and it works perfectly.

Here is the Process Builder configuration

[image: Create Child Record]

And, here is the child record created during Parent Lead record creation

[image: Child Record]

Comment: Are you firing this on record creation?

Comment: Ok looks like its working now. Not sure why it didnt before.  Will need to see if that was an one off situation

Comment: Yes, I am firing on record creation